# Install4j: installer:sys.installationDir inconsistent

Tags: java, install4j

The install4j variable sys.installationDir on MacOS (not the folder) returns just /Applications.

This makes sense since technically the directory the application was installed in was "/Applications" but I've used this variable inside my VM options to point to certain dependencies. This is causing me to have runtime errors. Is there another variable I should be using for this?

I've looked and I don't see any other options except to verify the platform and include the rest of the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the installer variable `${installer:sys.contentDir}` for that purpose, it always points at the directory where the distribution tree is installed.